# How do i fix this positioning?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace, portfolio

i'm trying to create personal portfolio website, but having problem with position or images itself. I've tried everything, nothing fixes it. For example: tried adding float left, display block. Not working. I gave up at the end. Please help guys.

```css
/* About - Portfolio */

.about-portfolio {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;}

.portfolio-header {
    margin-top: 20px;}

.about-style .portfolio-text {
    font-size: 40px;}

.about-portfolio:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}

.works-gallery {
    position: relative;}

.about-portfolio .grid-item {
    padding: 0px;}

.works-gallery img {
    width: 100%;}

.clearfix {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio" class="about-portfolio">
    
      <div class="portfolio-header">
       <h2 class="portfolio-text">Our Works</h2>
       <div class="divider"></div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
       <div class="works-gallery">
                            <a href="img/1.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
       <div class="works-gallery"> 
                            <a href="img/1.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                           </div> 
                        </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
      <div class="works-gallery">
                            <a href="img/1.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
   <!-- CLEARFIX -->
   
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
      <div class="works-gallery">
                            <a href="img/1.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-4.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
     
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
      <div class="works-gallery">
                            <a href="img/1.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-5.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
      <div class="works-gallery">
                            <a href="img/1.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-6.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                            </a>
       </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
```

[That whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJFwZ.jpg)

[after adding clearfix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhDHT.jpg)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that you don't have a clearfix class after your float, can you try removing the float and post a screenshot on what is the output?

Comment: Ok, but where to add clearfix class? @Fares Shawa

Comment: Usually a clearfix is added after every float element. so should be after the about.portfolio.. but first you need to create it.
.clearfix {clear: both;}

Comment: What exactly is your problem what you want to position?

Comment: @Fares Shawa Added the clearfix div after third col-sm-6 div and its kind of fixed but i m not sure if i did correctly?!

Comment: @Hiren Jungi no i want that portfolio images  to stick together but they re disordered creating big whitespace there. There is a output image under the codes, have a look :)

Comment: @Fares Shawa Thank you as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is already provided by Bootstrap library out of the box. All you need to do is take care not to break the necessary markup. Here's a working example:

```css
.img-responsive {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="portfolio" class="about-portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-header">
      <h2 class="portfolio-text">Our Works</h2>
      <div class="divider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/E8117F/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery"> 
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/999999/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/666666" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/E8117F/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery"> 
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/999999/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/666666" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might notice the only `CSS` rule I added is making small images fit their parent width. Also please notice there is only one row that contains all the `col-*`s. There is no need of any `.clearfix`.

---

If you want the images to be glued together, the simplest way would be to use this CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
  min-width: calc(100% + 30px);
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```css
.img-responsive {
  min-width: calc(100% + 30px);
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="portfolio" class="about-portfolio">
    <div class="portfolio-header">
      <h2 class="portfolio-text">Our Works</h2>
      <div class="divider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/E8117F/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery"> 
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/787878/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/666666" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/E8117F/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery"> 
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/999999/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div class="works-gallery">
          <a href="img/1.png">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/cccccc/666666" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrei Gheorghiu, that fixed my problem 100% :D

Comment: You're quite welcome. Happy coding! .. :: }<(((*> ::

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is quite common in grid layouts. If each column isn't exactly the same height they won't clear correctly.

You need to clear the first element of each new row. The clearfix div you've added will break the 2 column version of the layout. It's also worth noting that Bootstrap includes a clearfix class so the styling you've added is overriding defaults.

Start by wrapping all your grid items in a div.

```
<div class="work-gallery-container clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
            <div class="works-gallery">
                <a href="img/1.png">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        . . . ALL THE WAY TO THE LAST ITEM . . .

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 grid-item">
            <div class="works-gallery">
                <a href="img/1.png">
                    <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-6.jpg" alt="Image description" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div><!-- .work-gallery-container -->
```

Then apply some CSS.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .work-gallery-container .grid-item:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .work-gallery-container .grid-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

This assumes that you're using standard Bootstrap 3 breakpoints.